# select rows in multiplr conditions in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataFrame with many rows and columns and also have a specific condition list.

example DataFrame is below.

| index | fruit | recipe | size | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | apple | burn | big | 100 |
| 3 | banana | fry | small | 100 |
| 5 | apple | slice | big | 100 |
| 7 | apple | fry | small | 100 |
| 11 | pineapple | fry | small | 100 |
| 13 | mango | fry | small | 100 |

and

```
order = [("apple", "fry", "big"), ("apple", "fry", "big"), ...]
```

`isin` not working in multiple conditions.
I want to pick only combinations in order from DataFrame, not using iterrows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming each element in list `order` is of only 3 elements, you could do below without much performance issue:

```
df.loc[pd.Series(zip(df['fruit'], df['recipe'], df['size'])).isin(order)]
```

Comment: This code is simple and beautiful but only works with well ordered DataFrame. it is my fault. I forgot told index is shuffled condition .

Answer (score 0):

You can try [numpy broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to compare value

```py
order = [("apple", "fry", "big"), ("apple", "fry", "small")]

mask = ((df[['fruit', 'recipe', 'size']].to_numpy()[:, None] == np.array(order))
        .all(axis=-1)
        .any(axis=-1))

out = df[mask]
```

```
$ print(mask)

[False False False  True False False]

$ print(out)

   fruit recipe   size  price
3  apple    fry  small    100
```